# Data Cleansing, List iteration and closest match, Python or R

Tags: python, r

I have a problem of dirty data.

I have a list of ~600k names.

An example would be:

```
John Doe, 
JohnDoe, 
JohnDoe2, 
JohnDoe 84302,
```

I would like to use either `Python` or `R`, to iterate through this list and take the above closest match record (using a probability of closest match) and replace the current record, so the above list would look like:

```
Iteration 1:
John Doe,
John Doe,
JohnDoe2,
JohnDoe 84302,

Iteration 2:
John Doe,
John Doe,
John Doe,
JohnDoe 84302,

Iteration 3:
John Doe,
John Doe,
John Doe,
John Doe,
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Rather than asking how to do it, you should show what you've done on your own, and, if you get stuck, ask for help on specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @Martin Sand Christensen told you but if you don't have any idea of how to do it, here is an idea that you can develop on your own.

Considering that you need to find the closest name to the first at each iteration:

```
char <- c("John Doe", "JohnDoe", "JohnDoe2", "JohnDoe 84302")
for(i in 2:length(char)){
  if(!anyNA(str_match(char[2],str_split(char[1]," ")[[1]]))){
    char[i] <- char[1]
    print(char)
  }
}
```

We define char vector. Then we iterate over all other names. If we detect a name which contains separately "John" and "Doe", we set it to "John Doe". If there is only "John"   or only "Doe" in the name, we don't touch it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a close match, the [soundex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) might be what you need in order to solve the issue.

First, create a vector of strings. I have added some to your example.

```
x <- scan(what = character(), text = "
John Doe, 
JohnDoe, 
JohnDoe2, 
JohnDoe 84302,
Punit Patel,
PunitPatel,
Punit_Patel,
PunitPatel2
", sep = ",")

x <- x[trimws(x) != ""]
```

Now, there are several packages that implement soundex, `stringdist` is one of them. You need to `install.packages("stringdist")` first.

```
library(stringdist)

phonetic(x)    # Run this if you want to see the soundex codes

ave(x, phonetic(x), FUN = function(.x) .x[1])
#[1] "John Doe"    "John Doe"    "John Doe"    "John Doe"    "Punit Patel"
#[6] "Punit Patel" "Punit Patel" "Punit Patel"
```